# How to access data form in put request of class based views in django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I am currently having a problem with accessing my data stored in a data form. I'm passing it through ajax and its received by the put method in views.py. The problem is I only know how to access it through request.POST["item_name"] and for file request.FILES["photo"]. But apparently this doesnt work in put request. Can anyone please help?

**jQuery**

```
const form = new FormData();
const name = $('#edit-product-name-input-' + productID).val();
const quantity = $('#edit-product-quantity-input-' + productID).val();
const description = $('#edit-product-description-input-' + productID).val();
const price = $('#edit-product-price-input-' + productID).val();
const photo = $('#edit-product-photo-' + productID);

if (extractPhoto(photo)) {
    form.append('photo', extractPhoto(photo));
}
form.append('name', name);
form.append('price', price);
form.append('description', description);
form.append('quantity', quantity);
form.append('product_id', productID);

attachCSRF();
$.ajax({
    url: window.location.pathname + "products/",
    method: "PUT",
    data: form,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data["product"] + " edited");
        location.reload();
    },
    error: function (data) {
        if (data.responseJSON) {
            displayErrors(data.responseJSON);
        }
    }
```

**views.py**

```
@staticmethod
def put(request, stall_id):
    dict = {
        "product_name": request.body('name'),
        "description": request.body('description'),
        "price": request.body('price'),
        "quantity": request.body('quantity')
    }
    errors = handle_errors(dict)
    print(errors)

    if not errors:
        product = Product.objects.get(id=request.POST.get("product_id"))
        product.name = dict["product_name"]
        product.description = dict["description"]
        product.price = dict["price"]
        product.quantity = dict["quantity"]
        if 'photo' in request.FILES:
            product.photo = request.FILES.get('photo')
        product.save()


        data = {
            "product": product.name
        }

        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(data),
            content_type="application/json"
        )

    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(errors),
        content_type="application/json",
        status=400
    )
```

Comment: For both `PUT` and `POST` method , data should pass in same way, try to `print request.data` and see data is coming . For PUT and POST use `request.data['keyName'] `.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue and doing `QueryDict(request.body)` does not work for me.

Finally what I did is:

```
from django.http.multipartparser import MultiPartParser
put_data = MultiPartParser(request.META, request, request.upload_handlers).parse() # it will return a tuple object
put = put_data[0] # it will give you the QueryDict object with your form data.
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like when sending data via `x-www-form-urlencoded` it arrives in under the `request.body` as bytes.

** Don't use the `csrf_exempt` in your code I just used that for testing purposes.**

The below works for me:

```
from django.http import QueryDict


class Some(View):
    @csrf_exempt
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, *kwargs)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = QueryDict(request.body)
        print(data)
        return HttpResponse("Worked!")
```

The `data` variable is a `dict` so you can do this inside your put:

```
form = {
    "product_name": data.get('name'),
    "description": data.get('description'),
    "price": data.get('price'),
    "quantity": data.get('quantity')
}
```

Comment: hello thanks for the response! I edited that one I'm actually sending a form in my ajax. Would it still work the same? I have an imagine in my form thats probably whats causing me problems

Comment: Try parsing your form `request.body` with the `QueryDict` object and see if that works, but remember to update your code to access the data using dict syntax `[key_name]` or `.get(key_name)`.

Comment: Oh right I totally forgot about that thank you! I tried to access it as a function with a parameter